# Looking for a Classifier dealing with Real Time input

Tags: machine-learning, python, real-time

I need some suggestions on **'what classifiers I should use'** for the problem I am going to describe below.

I have a sensor that is feeding vectors at a rate of 100Hz. The vectors are 750 in length. Currently, I am taking ten vectors to form a 2d matrix/"image" because I am graphing it.

Each element in the vector represents the energy reflected at a certain distance. If this confuses you, you can think of the sensor as a radar.

My goal is to mount this sensor on a user's foot and measure their movements. Base on the measurements, I want to use ML to classify the movements, then provide feedback to the user.

Because movement is a continuous thing, I need an ML classifier that basically takes in multiple vectors and predicts base on that.

**Let me dumb my question down:**
I need ML classifiers that take in about ten vectors of size 750 and then classifies it.

**I am here asking for suggestions on the types of classifiers I should use to achieve time performance and accuracy.** I have looked through plenty of sites and could not find an answer as they are either too general or too confusing.

Please! Write with simple language, I am just a poor electrical engineer with very little ML background.

Comment: "Each vector is basically a ruler with 750 intervals" - are these intervals each a pair of an upper and lower bound? Or what exactly do you mean by that? Also, you write that for each interval you have a number indicating the reflected energy - am I right to assume this is a continuous variable then? And the problem you want to tackle with the model is predicting the reflected energy for a given vector, correct?

Comment: @Rickyfox see my edit